# Запятая между двумя прилагательными

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

*Они разглядывают **темное, ночное** небо.*
Нужно ставить запятую между двумя прилагательными или нет? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

*Они разглядывают т**емное ночное** небо.*

Пример: *На западе частыми зарницами освещается **темное ночное небо**, внизу серебрится река, а за покрытыми туманом лугами чернеет вдали лес.* [А. А. Есенина. Родное и близкое (1960-1979)]

Пояснение

Более вероятны неоднородные отношения (без запятой), но однородные отношения (с запятой) тоже возможны, что зависит от контекста.

Если это простое описание, то, возможно, автор описывает темное ночное небо, на котором нет звезд, тогда запятая не ставится.

Запятая ставится, если имеется в виду: темное, потому что ночное.